# Is boiling orange or lemon peels and drinking it as a tea healthy?

Tags: fruitarianism, fruits

In [the following article](http://www.just-health.net/Eating-Orange-Peels.html) we can read that you can you can 'boil the (orange) peel for around 15-20 minutes and drink it like a tea'.

Side note: Wouldn't you end up with essential oil instead where ingesting essential oils are not generally advised?

Assuming the fruits are organic, would it be safe and healthy to boil the orange (including lemon) peels and drink it as a tea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only it is safe, but [my family has been doing this to make fruit jam](http://www.livestrong.com/article/238484-how-to-make-pectin-orange-peel/) for generations now. Orange and lemon peels are a great source of pectin, which makes jams get their jelly texture.